# Shimano Nexus 8 Hub Alignment Mark No Longer Visible

Tags: shimano, internally-geared-hub, adjustment

I've got a Shimano Nexus 8 IGH, and was previously able to adjust it properly by aligning the two yellow tick marks in the 'window' as described [here](https://aseasyasridingabike.wordpress.com/2013/02/01/a-simple-guide-to-adjusting-a-shimano-nexus-hub-gear/).

[image: Shimano Nexus 8 adjustment guides]

However, I then removed and replaced the rear wheel a couple of times to change a tire, clean, etc. However, I can now no longer see the second (outside) yellow tick mark in the window, and can't seem to get the gear adjustment dialed in without it. I have been using the painted yellow tick marks, but lining them up doesn't seem to dial in the shifting quite as nicely as it did when I lined up the tick marks in the window. Any idea what went wrong, and how I can get the second tick mark back again?

EDIT: It looks like someone added a photo--thanks. My issue is that when I look at my hub, the second (bottom in this photo) tick mark is not visible no matter what I do, so I can't use it for alignment. The window is clean, and the first tick mark is clearly visible.

Answer (score 1):

You can flip the bike over; there is a second set of alignment marks on the bottom of the cassette joint.

[Shimano Nexus Hub Adjustment](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/nexus-mech.html)

[image: Sheldon Brown Nexus 8 setup diagram]

Scroll down to "Gear Adjustment"; there are drawings that are helpful. This page in general has great information on Shimano's internally geared hubs; worth the read.

You can also purchase a [new cassette joint](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001GSKUYQ). I've never seen the adjustment marks become completely eradicated; if you cleaned the bike with strong solvents or cleaners, this may have lightened them.

Comment: JonR. Thanks. As I said, I have been using the secondary marks for alignment, but haven't been able to get the shifting quite as sharp as when the marks in the window were visible.

Comment: @DarrenCope When I had one of those hubs I used to tune the adjustment by feel more than using the marks because my bike made seeing the marks almost impossible. I'd adjust it as best you can, then try half a turn on the adjuster at a time until it works properly. Just remember which way you're turning :)

Comment: @DarrenCope Be careful doing this. While the hub will shift at an out-of-adjustment position, it will not be completely lined up. This will prematurely wear out pawls, even though the hub will feel fine while shifting. Unless you are very confident adjusting the hub this way, I would not recommend this. You can also disassemble the cassette joint to try and clean it, making the adjustment marks visible again (two Phillips screws, very easy) if you don't want to buy a new cassette joint.